# What should we do if a ghost reaches out to us first (as opposed to us reaching out to/consulting ghosts)?

Tags: halacha, nevua-prophecy, sorcery-magic-kishuf, afterlife

Deut. 18:10-11 says:

> לא ימצא בך מעביר בנו ובתו באש קסם קסמים מעונן ומנחש ומכשף וחבר חבר
> **ושאל אוב וידעני** ודרש אל המתים
>
> Let no one be found among you who consigns his son or daughter to the fire, or who is an augur, a soothsayer, a diviner, a sorcerer,one who casts spells, **or one who consults ghosts or familiar spirits**, or one who inquires of the dead.

Thus one should not consult ghosts. The context of this verse however is more about idolatry than say, mere interaction. This is also repeated in Leviticus 19:31. That being said, many Jewish sources have historically also advised against any involvement with ghosts. For instance, Ibn Ezra says to not seek to request their services (as Saul did I Samuel 28:8). This implies that the main prohibition is to use the ghosts to inquire from them - i.e. reaching out to ghosts first. My question is then, what if the (neutral) ghosts are the ones who reach out to us (to say, only chat with us)? Are we to simply ignore the ghost and avoid the contact? What if the said ghost refuses to go away (if we ignore it or if we tell it to go away)? This all relates to how far would the halachic prohibitions apply and what we should do in such a case for its questionable whether it would even be a halachic prohibition in this context.

The answer to this question should probably avoid sources like Rambam who didn't believe that ghosts existed and/or could be communicated with. This question is according to the other perspective.

Comment: You could ask the same about dead inquiring of you, assuming that's even possible. I think the point of the prohibition is not to _summon_ the dead, not about whether you should ignore them if they tap you on the shoulder. And the translation of "ghosts" is questionable.

Comment: @shmosel Hm, that's pretty interesting. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: See Sefer ha-Miswoth Negative Commandment #8 and 9 as well as Hilkhoth 'Abhoda Zara 6:1-2 to to get a better grasp of the parameters of this prohibition. The rituals of obh/yid'oni and its worship are not simply "consulting ghosts." I'm not sure why the other answers have glossed over this fundamental step in attempting to answer your question.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Hm, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how Abhoda Zara 6:1-2 applies here since that's more related to idolatry and summoning evil spirits etc., and not just talking to a netural ghost who approaches you first. The quote was more of an inspiration in the sense that we cannot consult ghosts and generally speaking, are to avoid them - but then, what if it happens that they approach us first and are netural and just want to chat or even share some information on their own will? Also don't see how Sefer Hamitzvot #8 and #9 apply here. Especially since Rambam has a bad example.

Comment: @setszu they are applicable here as they concern the specific prohibition you asked about (שאל אוב וידעני). The so-called prohibition of "consulting ghosts" which you cite from Deut. 18:11 is a poor translation of the prohibition against the ritual/worship of obh and yid'oni. The structure of this prohibition is explained in the aforementioned sources. If you are simply using the pesuqim as a springboard, then a more natural sequence is a) is there a prohibition against consulting ghosts? b) what are its parameters?

Comment: The way you have this set-up, it appears that you believe/assume that the specific section of the pasuq you cite intends such a prohibition and that you are seeking clarity on how far that extends. If that is not what you intended, it would be appropriate to edit your question to reflect your actual intent.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Ah, I thought my question was clear from the title, but I understand how it could be understood this way. I'll edit it eventually to clarify. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @setszu please define ghost and explain how you know it's even possible that one would approach a person for conversation on its own?

Comment: @RabbiKaii A ghost is a transcedental and conscious essence of a person who is on the Earth at a particular point in time. In an elevated state of spiritual purity and transcedence, it is possible for a ghost to approach a person and talk to them. And why wouldn't a ghost have the ability to approach a person? They have basically full consciousness and are like a person, just immaterial.

Comment: @setszu The average person has not experienced or likely heard of such a thing, so bringing at least one example or some other positive reason that ghosts coming to people for conversation about the afterlife would be of great aid to the question. I would also put your definition and where you get it from in the OP

Comment: Interestingly, the Targum Yonasan translates [And if any person turns to ghosts and familiar spirits and goes astray after them](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.6?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Leviticus&lang2=en) as [And the man who turns aside to inquire of the impostors, or to seek to bring up the dead](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.6?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Leviticus&lang2=en). According to this, do ghosts even excist? Or....

Comment: [Rabbi Yehudah Levi (cont.), in The Science in Torah, explains that there are two traditional opinions on this subject. One view accepts that it is possible to communicate with the dead but we are not allowed to do so. However, Maimonides took another approach. He decried all types of witchcraft, sorcery and communication with the dead. These forms of invoking spirits are not only nonsense but pagan activities, undermining the pure monotheism of Judaism.](https://www.ou.org/life/inspiration/jewish-view-ghosts/) - does this answer your question whether we should interact with them? Beside Rmbm.

Comment: @Shmuel I already explained all this in my previous comments. Given what I added in the question description, Yehudah Levi's stuff doesnt answer it and it uses Deut. 18:11 which I already address in my post and the verse is more about idolatry etc. Moreover, it doesnt answer my question of what happens if the ghost is the one coming to you to chat, not you inquiring a ghost. As for Rambam, he a heretic, it does not destroy monotheism for we recognize that theres one and only one G-d, blessed be He, and worship Him exclusively. I addressed Rambam before, & its not nonsense, etc. so no.

Comment: If it's not obvious already, you're not going to find many like-minded members here. The vast majority of Torah-observant Jews today treat the Rambam and any _rishon_ with deference and respect. I don't know if there's an official policy as to what viewpoints are accepted here, but if your premise is that the Rambam's opinion carries no weight, you're operating in a different framework than most of us and are probably wasting your efforts.

Comment: @shmosel So be it. I will still try to bounty the question later to see if I can get some other responses.

Comment: "The sources for him [Shemuel b. Hofni, Gaon of Sura] being a heretic are me, myself & I" OK, so an altogether unsubstantiated claim. You are free to disagree with a particular view (ghosts do or do not exist). However your lack of basic respect for Geonim and Rishonim universally regarded as baale ha-mesorah is something I would advise you reconsider. It is worth noting that our Hakhamim taught that one who disgraces a talmid hakham is an apiqores (heretic). Despite there being plenty to discuss in regards to your question, I can no longer in good conscience participate in this.

Comment: You have to summon the "ghost". They don't just appear to you.

Comment: @N.T. Not true at all. We have accounts of people simply being at the graveyard and overhearing discussions of ghosts. One doesn't have to summon them, they can just come or remain.

Comment: Related: [What constitutes communicating with the dead?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109823/6592)

Comment: **Everyone**: this is not the place to debate if ghosts exist or not. The OP should provide a definition of what he is talking about within the range of on-topic Jewish sources and all answers should work within that framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the writings by [Rabbi Ullman](https://wp.rabbiullman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/05-R.Ullman-self-study-Ghosts-and-Apparitions.pdf), he quotes the following sources:

Yoreh Deah 179:14
To take an oath from a sick person to return after his death in order to answer whatever one may ask is permitted. And there are those who permit this even after death if he doesn't swear the body of the deceased, just his soul.

Furthermore, Rabbi Ullman quotes a story “Reb Yechiel, the father of the Rosh, and R' Shelomo HaCohen made a pact with each other that whoever died first would appear to the other and reveal what occurred to him after death. R' Yechiel died first, and at his burial in front of the assembled congregation, R' Shelomo reminded the deceased of their pact. After several days, R' Yechiel appeared to R' Shelomo while he was learning in the synagogue. R' Yechiel told him that he has great pleasure in heaven and he was also given permission to appear to people, and even to go to his home as when he was alive. Six months later, at midnight on the Sabbath, R' Yechiel appeared to his wife and told her that the authorities had decreed that all Jews in the province would be murdered in the morning. She fled with her family during the night and in this way they were saved.
[from Chida, Shem HaGedolim, Gedolim, R' Eliezer bar Natan 199. The Chida writes that he found a hand written manuscript of R' Chaim Vital which records finding a letter of R' Yehuda, son of the Rosh, in which he attests to hearing this account from the Rosh himself.

Finally, Rabbi Ullman quotes Kala Rabati ch. 2:
Rabbi Akiva went to a certain place where he found a person who was carrying a load on his shoulders but was having a hard time walking with it and was screaming and groaning.
He said to him, what have you done?' He replied, there wasn't a sin I didn't transgress and now there are watchmen over me and they don't let me rest.' Rabbi Akiva asked him,
'did you leave over a son?' He replied, 'by your life, don't delay me [by your questions] for I am in dread of the angels that hit me with rays of fire and they say to me, why don't you go faster?' He asked [again], who did you leave behind?' He replied, 'I left behind a pregnant wife.' Rabbi Akiva went to the place [of the apparition]. He asked them, where is the son of that person?' They replied, 'may his memory be blotted out and his bones crushed.' He asked, why?' They replied, he was a bandit who destroyed people and distressed the populace. In addition he had illicit relations with a betrothed girl on Yom Kippur.' He went to the home of his pregnant wife and waited until she gave birth. He circumcised [the son] and when he grew older he set him up in the synagogue to pray for the congregation. Some time later Rabbi Akiva went to the place where he had originally seen the apparition]. He appeared to him and told him, 'may your mind be put at ease for you have put my mind at ease.

© All rights reserved to R. Yirmiyahu Ullman. Any copy of this material must include the following: This is one of a ten part self-study series taken from www. RabbiUllman.com.

Comment: I love these stories so much, but in all of these, we cannot ascertain that there was a both-ways communication i.e. ghost talking to people and people replying and speaking to the ghost. In all of the cases, it seems that in theory, it could be that the ghost simply appear and started speaking to the people and the people could've just said nothing. As there a way to confirm that any of the people actually replied especially Rabbi Akiva in Tractate Kallah Rabbati? I really appreciate you quoting the extent of the halacha from Yoreh De'ah, that is very helpful.

Comment: What's not clear is if Yoreh Deah 179:14 refers to asking someone the question that they want an answer to *before* they die, & then the ghost appears to provide the answer, or whether one just makes an oath & then after the person dies & their ghost arrives, they ask them the questions. But, if according to some, one can make an oath with their spirit, that might refer *only* to an oath (which is also a form of communication with the person in "afterlife") & then obviously by implication, one has to ask the person questions only *after* they appear, thus establishing communication with them.

Comment: Based on this interpretation, one could understand the halacha regarding this to indicate that in such a situation, a communication where both communicate with each other would be permissible. Additionally, one could with this, at least by implication, gauge that there likely was at least some contact between the living person and the ghost, or even if there wasn't, there wouldn't necessarily be an issue. Perhaps, due to getting to the point and not wasting too much space given the historical context, it wasn't important to include the private discussions which the oath would imply.

Comment: Therefore, with this, it would be tolerated to interact minimally with a netural ghost should they be the one to approach the person and there was at least some kind of agreement before or after in conjunction with receiving permission from the Divine. I guess with this, my question would be answered.

Answer (score 2):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קסו - שלא לנחש לעונן ולכשף](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html) says

> **:סעיף ה'**
> אָסוּר לִדְרוֹשׁ בִּמְכַשְּׁפִים אֶלָּא בִּמְקוֹם סַכָּנַת נְפָשׁוֹת, אוֹ אִם בָּא לוֹ אֵיזֶה חֳלִי עַל יְדֵי כִשּׁוּף אוֹ מִקְרֶה וְרוּחַ רָעָה, מֻתָּר לְהִתְרַפְּאוֹת עַל יְדֵי מְכַשֵׁף גּוֹי.‏

> One may not deal with magic, (divinations, etc. - as you can see from the title of the section), but if, [for example] one has an ailment caused by magic, bad spirits [or the like], one may go to a non-Jew to get healed.

So it seems, that one does not "ignore" contact with the spirits/ghosts/etc. but, as a Jew, one may not interact with them. One may use the help of a non-Jew to rid oneself of their presence.

Comment: Is every ghost a bad spirit though? What if the ghost just wants to talk to someone or give them information which the person hasn't asked for? And this is talking about ailments, but what if there are no ailments? I will still upvote this at least since I didn't know about visiting a non-Jew for ailments of this kind. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @setszu - not my area of expertise, I can't even decide if I believe they exist (nowadays) , but as the verse lumps them all together, they seem to have similar rules, laws and characteristics, one assumes.

Comment: I think that ghosts definitely do exist and this is shown both in the Torah I think and in the Talmud. Presumably, when it says "bad spirits [or the like]" in the verse its talking about evil ghosts and dmons, not necessarily a regular ghost of a person who simply died and approach someone to chat with them. The latter simply doesn't seem to be a focus of this, so I don't think it can count.

Comment: As I said "nowadays". As you pointed out, historically they were discussed in detail, as if they were a (somewhat) common occurrence.

Comment: Yeah nowadays too - there's no real big difference between today and before. They are not a particularly uncommon occurrance.

Comment: These halachot are dealt with in great detail in SA YD 179, and commentary.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I already explained why SA YD 179 doesn't answer my question specifically and I'm not sure what commentary you're talking about.

Comment: @setszu yes, I am backing you up, I don't think that halacha is about ghosts. Would have to go through it again

Comment: @RabbiKaii Oh ok then, I misunderstood. my bad.

Comment: How does this jive with the law of מכשפה לא תחיה? Would this law be the same in eras when jews ruled eretz yisroel?

Comment: @larry909 Of course, one needs a court, but also this probably means that if someone threw a magic spell on the other person, or has somehow attracted bad spirits, one may go for healing. However, the law of מכשפה לא תחיה as stated by Rashi on Exodus 22:17:1 talks specifically about practitioners of witchcraft and evil magic. So those are two different things if I'm understand your comment correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There's a story in the Talmud (Brachot 18) about a fellow who goes to sleep in the graveyard for a few years in a row, on Yom Kippour evening.

He hears ghosts (souls/spirits of young girls buried there) talking about when will be the best time to plant in the upcoming year.

He implements what he learnt and his crop succeeded.

**We do not see that he was condemned for listening or acting on his information. We do see that he did not interact with the ghosts.**

The full story, as translated [here](https://etzion.org.il/en/talmud/studies-gemara/midrash-and-aggada/two-spirits-graveyard-and-perils-poverty) along with some analysis of what this all could mean:

There was a story of a pious man who gave a coin to a pauper during years of famine.  His wife became angry with him, and he went to sleep in the cemetery.  He heard two spirits talking to each other.

One said to the other:  Let us go travel in the world and hear from behind the curtain what punishment is coming to the world.

She said to her: I cannot because I am buried in a mat of reeds.  You go and tell me what you hear.

She went out and came back.

Her friend said: What did you hear behind the curtain?

She said to her: I heard that anyone who plants at the time of the first rainfall will have their crops struck by hail.

He [the pious fellow] went and planted during the second rainfall.   The entire world's crops were stricken but not those of this fellow.

The next year, he went to sleep in the cemetery.   He heard two spirits talking to each other.

One said to the other:  Let us go travel in the world and hear from behind the curtain what punishment is coming to the world.

She said to her: I cannot because I am buried in a mat of reeds.  You go and tell me what you hear.

She went out and came back.

Her friend said: What did you hear behind the curtain?

She said to her: I heard that anyone who plants at the time of the second rainfall will have their crops struck by blight.

He [the pious fellow] went and planted at time of the first rainfall.   The entire world's crops were struck by blight but not those of this fellow.

His wife asked him:  How come last year, everyone's crops were stricken except yours, and now everyone's crops were blighted except yours?

He told her the whole story.  They said: It was not many days before a quarrel developed between the pious fellow's wife and the mother of that [deceased] girl.

She said to her: Come and I will show you your daughter buried in a mat of reeds.

The next year, he went to sleep in the cemetery.   He heard those spirits talking to each other.

One said to the other:  Let us go travel in the world and hear from behind the curtain what punishment is coming to the world.

She said to her: Leave me be.  The words passed between us are heard among the living.

Comment: Wow, what an interesting story! I love it! In this case though, the ghosts did not approach him though. Still, it helps to solve a piece of the puzzle, so thank you very much for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

A literal reading of [Ketubot 103a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ketubot.103a.25?lang=bi) would seem to suggest that R. Yehuda HaNasi would come and interact with his family after his death:

> תנו רבנן, בשעת פטירתו של רבי, אמר: לבני אני צריך. נכנסו בניו אצלו. אמר להם: הזהרו בכבוד אמכם. נר יהא דלוק במקומו, שולחן יהא ערוך במקומו, מטה תהא מוצעת במקומה ... מאי טעמא? כל בי שמשי הוה אתי לביתיה. ההוא בי שמשא אתאי שבבתא, קא קריה אבבא, אמרה אמתיה: שתיקו, דרבי יתיב. כיון דשמע, שוב לא אתא, שלא להוציא לעז על צדיקים הראשונים.‏
>
> The Sages taught: At the time of the passing of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi, he said: I need my sons. His sons entered his room. He said to them: Be careful with the honor of your mother. He said further: My lamp should be lit in its usual place, my table should be set in its usual place, and the bed should be arranged in its usual place ... What is the reason he made these requests? Every Shabbat eve, even after his passing, Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi would come to his house as he had done during his lifetime. It happened on a certain Shabbat eve that a neighbor came by and called and knocked at the door. His maidservant said to her: Be quiet, for Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi is sitting. When he heard his maidservant reveal his presence to the neighbor, he did not come again, so as not to cast aspersions on earlier righteous individuals who did not appear to their families following their death.

In fact, [Sefer Hassidim 1129](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_Chasidim.1129.1?lang=bi) goes as far as to write that R. Yehuda HaNasi would recite *kiddush* for those present.

Comment: Fascinating. This implies that since he was the one to come to the family first and establish interaction with them, there was no particular issues. This is probably the closest answer to what I'm looking for so far. It seems that in such a case, we may not have to avoid all contact and ignore the ghost, and the halachic prohibitions do not extend and apply to this. And like someone else said, if the ghost refuses to go away, it might be an evil ghost due to harassment and one is to go to a non-Jew to have it exorcised I think. So ultimately, I guess we just react normally, & can speak to them

Comment: Hm, but on a second reading, it does not necessarily mean that there was a 1 to 1 contact between any of them though, for the maidservant could've simply seen the ghost. And R. Yehuda HaNasi could've been reciting for example kiddush for those present without them necessarily acknowledging it.